# Godot 2D WASD Movement

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a trouble with a 2D Godot Project.

I wrote the following code in the KinematicBody2D script:

extends KinematicBody2D

```
export var speed = 250
var motion = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):
    motion = Vector2.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        motion.y = -speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down"):
        motion.y = speed
    motion = move_and_slide(motion)
    pass # Replace with function body.
```

The problem is that my player is only moving a few pixels and stops while I'm pressing the W, A, S, D or the arrow keys.

What I've done wrong?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `is_action_just_pressed` tells you if the named action※ was *just* pressed. It will not continue returning true if the action is held.

This, combined with the fact that you are erasing `motion` each physic frame `motion = Vector2.ZERO`, result in the object moving one physics frame and then it stops.

If you want to know if the action is currently pressed - independently of when it began being pressed - use `is_action_pressed` instead.

※: The actions you can use with these functions are configured in the Project Settings. You will find them on the "Input Map" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing *is_action_just_pressed* with *is_action_pressed* which will detect the holding down of a button rather than a single press which will result in a continuous motion rather than a movement of a few pixels.
Also *motion = Vector2.ZERO* is resetting the motion to 0 every time the game updates. This is causing the player to stop.

Try doing something like this:

```
export var speed = 250
var motion = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -speed
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = speed
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        motion.y = -speed
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        motion.y = speed

    motion = move_and_slide(motion)
```